# Can this switch and while loop be simplified in C#?

Tags: c#

```
while (p3.Alive || p2.Alive)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int victim = rnd.Next(1, 3);

            switch (victim)
            {
                case 1:
                    p1.Attack(p2, 2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    p1.Attack(p3, 2);
                    break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

p2 and p3 and objects of class Person. They are about to be killed off on random by the killer, p1. But when I look at it, I feel like there could be a better solution because what if I had 1000 objects of class Person ready to be killed? I just can't seem to get the p2 and p3 to be easily programmed variables.

The while loop is the same. What if I had 1000 objects. Or even just 10. How can I write this so that the condition is "while anyone but the killer is alive" and an "if" or "switch" which attacks anyone chosen by the Random rnd?

The question is badly written in the topic. I don't know how I could summarize all this into a short question. I'll edit it if anyone has a good suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Why not have a list of players?

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` object at each iteration, that could make the outcomes predictable because they all start at 'the first number from a semi-random list'. You are probably being saved here by the `Sleep(2000)`, but still it's never a good idea and never needed.

Comment: Also this code makes it possible to attack a player that is not alive anymore. Waste of "attack resources" and a big logic flaw.

Comment: @PeterB Hey, I did as you said and tested it and it works better now, thank you. How can I prevent him from attacking someone if already dead then? What would you do?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it is essentially a coin toss with 2 outcomes; 2 outcomes can be modelled with the "conditional" operator:

```
var target = rnd.Next(0,2) == 0 ? p2 : p3;
pi.Attack(target);
```

For larger groups, having the possible targets in a list or array may be useful; then you can essentially do:

```
var target = list[rnd.Next(list.Count)];
```

Or with C# 8, "switch expressions" may be useful:

```
var target = rnd.Next(4) switch (
   case 0: p1,
   case 1: p2,
   case 2: p3,
   case 3: p4,
   case _: default
);
```

Comment: The ternary operator is costly in term of processing.

Comment: @Hassaan it is a single conditional jump (typically brtrue or brfalse - or their "short" forms) - certainly not "expensive" by most definitions; it may cause a CPU branch prediction fail, and there *are* cases where that might be relevant, but frankly, that is going to be **absolutely nothing** compared to the cost of generating the next random number, so: I'm going to ignore it completely. In the scenario presented, a conditional is absolutely free

Answer (score 3):

Fixes for all issues:

- Only make one Random object
- Use a List to avoid repeated code
- Don't attack opponents that are no longer Alive

```
using System.Collections.Generic;             // provides the List type

Random rnd = new Random();
var opponents = new List<Player> { p2, p3 };  // add more as needed

while (true)
{
    opponents.RemoveAll(x => !x.Alive);  // only keep live enemies (efficient: does not create new List)
    if (opponents.Count == 0)            // if nobody left --> exit loop
        break;

    int victim = rnd.Next(0, opponents.Count);
    p1.Attack(opponents[victim]);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: creating an array every time, and using the `Where` predicate each time - are both unnecessarily expensive here; I'd be more inclined to populate a list at the start, and basically do `var target = opponents[victim]; p1.Attack(target); if (!target.IsAlive) { opponents.Remove(target); }`

Comment: Thanks, probably a better approach, unless opponents could also die for other reasons (e.g. old age) outside the control of this loop ;-)

Comment: indeed; in that case, `List<T>` has a predicate-based remove all method, so - *before* picking a target: `opponents.RemoveAll(x => !x.IsAlive);` - the predicate will be hoisted into a static by the C# compiler, so that it doesn't cost an allocation per call

Comment: Followed through. Just a thought: maybe SO should introduce PRs and Code Reviews for answers (and questions!)

Comment: @PeterB This looks good, but I would still here have to add the 1000 people to the array. 
- I also don't understand what we're doing with the Where and x equal to or less than x.Alive and all that. What are we asking? 
- And what is opponents.length in the if statement?

Comment: @PeterB - And it seems you're not counting the object which kills the other objects. So the array tries to get an index of 3, not 2.

Comment: If you just follow the (now updated) code, you will see that it Just Works. Note that `p1` is *not* in this List (previously the Array) so it does not count towards the number of items in it. Also, if you have like a thousand `Player` variables already (p1..p1000), I'd say that is a very, very good reason to start using a `List` everywhere, and not just for this little part. And if you have issues converting your 1000-variables code to a List, then please create a new Question. And perhaps Accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @PeterB p1.Attack(opponents[victim]) throws this exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Comment: I have tested the above code multiple times and it works. If it fails for you then your code is different. If you can't fix it, instead of discussing here how it might be different or what might need to be fixed, please [post a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).